# Spring Boot application dependency library fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a Spring Boot application ( created in http://start.spring.io -JDK8, Spring Boot 2.6.6 ). I am able to build it and start it.

I added a dependency to the existing library :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.connect_responsibilitymgr_services</groupId>
    <artifactId>connect-responsibilitymgr-services</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In my implementation I got an instance of the class defined in the dependent library :

```
ToolkitApi toolkitApi = new ToolkitApi();
UserProfile profile = toolkitApi.getUserProfile("123456");
```

I am getting a NullPointerException inside the implementation of "getUserProfile":

```
public UserProfile getUserProfile(String id) throws Exception {
        
        try {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();            
            headers.set("toolkit-token",
                    CryptoUtils.decrypt(**toolkitConfiguration**.getClientToken(), **toolkitConfiguration**.getEncryptedKey()));
```

where "toolkitConfiguration" is not instantiated. It's NULL;

In ToolkitApi implementation Bean is being Autowired :

```
@Controller
public class ToolkitApi {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ToolkitApi.class);

    @Autowired
    private GISToolConfiguration.ToolkitConfigInfo toolkitConfiguration;
```

....

```
@Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("toolkit")
    ToolkitConfigInfo toolkitConfigInfo() {
        return new ToolkitConfigInfo();
    }

    public static class ToolkitConfigInfo {
        
        private String hostname;
        
        private String port;
        
        private String clientToken;
        
        private String encryptedKey;
```

all the properties of the ToolkitConfigInfo are defined in "application.properties" and I am able read them.
So my "GISToolConfiguration.ToolkitConfigInfo toolkitConfiguration" is never getting instantiated. I am new to Spring Boot and to me it looks like a Bean in dependent library is not getting instantiated for whatever reason. What could be a problem?

Comment: Is the Bean `ToolkitConfigInfo` that you showed the `GISToolConfiguration.ToolkitConfigInfo` ?

Comment: yes, it's an inner class :

public class GISToolConfiguration {
...
@Bean
 @ConfigurationProperties("toolkit")
 ToolkitConfigInfo toolkitConfigInfo() {
  return new ToolkitConfigInfo();
 }

 public static class ToolkitConfigInfo {
  
  private String hostname;
  
  private String port;
  
  private String clientToken;
  
  private String encryptedKey;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating your `toolkitApi` with `new`:

```
ToolkitApi toolkitApi = new ToolkitApi();
```

There Spring DI cannot inject the `toolkitConfiguration`. Let Spring inject you that `toolkitApi` where you use it.

Comment: It looks like it's the right way to do it. I am trying to inject it but getting compilation Error : Could not autowire, "No beans of 'ToolkitApi' type found. I am doing it in my main Application class. I think it's a problem.

Comment: I added @ComponentScan(<path-toToolkitApi-package>) and it started to initialize it. This is definitely the right way to do it. Thanks a million!

Comment: you're welcome. Don't forget to upvote the answer and accept it if it was helpful to you, please :)